# How do I figure out what is answering a DNS resolution call?

Tags: dns, host-name-resolution

Let's say I have inside of my hosts file an entry for `foobar`, how do I find out if that file is used or if a remote DNS is answering the resolution for `foobar`?

Do any of the basic utilities give back that information?

`dig +trace` isn't showing me what I want to know

```
dig +trace localhost

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> +trace localhost
;; global options: +cmd
;; Received 28 bytes from 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) in 0 ms

dig +trace google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> +trace google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Received 28 bytes from 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) in 0 ms
```

I would expect it to tell me that the lookup is resolving to `hosts` for `localhost` and my dns server (whichever one) for `google.com`. If I make a call internally using [`getaddrinfo(3)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getaddrinfo) is it hitting the hosts file or the upstream dns server when resolving `localhost`.

Comment: @Christopher not a dupe, I clarified.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Neither of those are even close to what I'm looking for.. I want to know whether or not `getaddrinfo` is hitting the hosts file or the upstream dns server when resolving localhost.

Answer (score 1):

`dig` is a DNS troubleshooting tool: you either specify explicitely the DNS server you want to query or, if you do not, it will use what is specified in your `resolv.conf`. As written in its documentation:

> Unless it is told to query a specific name server, dig will try each of the servers listed in /etc/resolv.conf. If no usable server addresses are found, dig will send the query to the local host.

For any other application on the system, needing to do a DNS resolution, this will be under the control of `/etc/nsswitch.conf` that lists the source of information to query to resolve hostname, like:

> hosts:          files myhostname mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4

which for example shows that the `glibc` will first have a look in `/etc/hosts` (the `files` token) and only later on do a DNS query (the `dns` token), again using the content of `resolv.conf`

If you want to be 100% sure for a given application, you will need to run it inside a `strace` call.

Comment: To run a test query using the system APIs, use `getent hosts` or `getent ahosts`.  To see if the result it provides is coming from a given service, you could use `getent -s files ahosts` - try each service in the order specified in nsswitch.conf.